# How to define a copy constructor for a const template parameter?

Tags: c++, stl, constants, std, copy-constructor

I'm creating a custom iterator and I'm having trouble satisfying the scenario where I create a `const` iterator and initialize it with a non-`const` `begin()`. This is legal according to the STL and can be demonstrated with std::string:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string::iterator a;
    string::const_iterator b = a;

    return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out how to make it work:

```
template<typename T>
class some_class {
};

int main() {
    some_class<int> a;

    // Works OK!
    const some_class<int> const_b = a;

    // error: conversion from 'some_class<int>' to non-scalar type 'const some_class<const int>'
    const some_class<const int> const_c = a;

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

[@ALEXANDER KONSTANTINOV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3943956/alexander-konstantinov) provided a solution but it does not satisfy all possible STL test cases. I'm testing [@Bo Persson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/597607/bo-persson)'s suggestion next. Changing the constructor to `const some_class<U>& other` will allow it to compile but then `iterator a = const_iterator b` would also erroneously be true.

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class some_class {
public:
    some_class() {
    }

    template<typename U>
    some_class(some_class<U>& other) {
    }
};

namespace name {
    typedef some_class<int> iterator;
    typedef const some_class<const int> const_iterator;
}

int main() {
    string::iterator a;
    string::const_iterator b = a;
    const string::iterator c;
    string::iterator d = c;
    string::const_iterator e = c;

    name::iterator f;
    name::const_iterator g = f;
    const name::iterator h;
    name::iterator i = h;
    name::const_iterator j = h; // <- Error

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

There seems to be some confusion regarding adding `const` to the constructor. Here is a test case:

```
// This is not allowed by the STL
//string::const_iterator _a;
//string::iterator _b = _a; // <- Error!

// This should NOT compile!
name::const_iterator _a;
name::iterator _b = _a;
```

Comment: Have you checked how the standard library achieves that?

Comment: [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) combined with [`std::remove_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) and `std::is_same` lets you conditionally provide a suitable constructor.

Comment: A popular method is to make `const_iterator` a base class of `iterator`. That way there is an implicit conversion from derived to base.

Comment: @Bo, your suggestion appears to be working as expected and answers the question fully. Am I missing any caveats or is this solid? Otherwise please submit as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - you cannot assume that `std::string::const_iterator` is just "const version" of regular iterator - like this `const std::string::iterator`.

When you look at your STL library implementation (this is just example from gcc4.9.2 STL header for basic_string):

```
  typedef __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<pointer, basic_string>  iterator;
  typedef __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const_pointer, basic_string>
                                                        const_iterator;
```

As you can see - what differs both iterators is the return pointer value - `pointer` vs `const_pointer` - and that is the case - "const iterator" is not something that cannot change - but something that returns const pointer/references so you cannot modify the values the iterator iterates over.

So - we can investigate further and see how the desired copying from non const to const version was achieved:

```
  // Allow iterator to const_iterator conversion
  template<typename _Iter>
    __normal_iterator(const __normal_iterator<_Iter,
          typename __enable_if<
           (std::__are_same<_Iter, typename _Container::pointer>::__value),
          _Container>::__type>& __i) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
    : _M_current(__i.base()) { }
```

So, basically - this constructor accepts any instance of the same template (`__normal_iterator`) - but it has `enable_if` closure to allow only instance of const pointer.

I believe you shall do the same in your case

1. Have real const_iterator - not just const version of regular iterator
2. And have template constructor from const_iterator with enable_if restriction to disallow constructing from anything (I mean iterator over ints from iterator over std::strings)

---

As per your example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class some_class {
public:
    some_class() {
    }

    template <typename U>
    using allowed_conversion_from_non_const_version = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::remove_cv_t<T>,U>::value>;

    template<typename U, typename EnableIf = allowed_conversion_from_non_const_version<U>>
    some_class(const some_class<U>&) {
    }

    template<typename U, typename EnableIf = allowed_conversion_from_non_const_version<U>>
    some_class& operator = (const some_class<U>&) {
    }
};
```

Two things to read from this example:

1. Assignment operator is also needed
2. You shall enable only from non-const to const version - and this is achieved by combination of `enable_if`/`remove_cv` (`remove_const` also works - but why not construct also volatile version - anyway `cv` is shorter than `const`)

Comment: I used `int` and `const int` in my example as a substitution for `pointer` and `const_pointer` for brevity. Initial testing with @Bo Persson's suggestion seems to be working for the test cases but I'll need to investigate it and your suggestion further. I have to step away but it seems as though your suggestion provides the same solution but without the need for inheritance and also drops off the `const` from the `const_iterator` typedef.

Comment: I haven't been able to make this work with my test case. Can you provide an example? This seems similar to @Tony D's suggestion.

Comment: @Zhro - done. I check it compiles fine under clang and gcc.

Comment: Looks great. Thanks so much; this has been a very valuable thread for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a template copy constructor for your class

```
template<typename T>
class some_class {

public:
    template<typename U> friend class some_class;

    some_class()
    {
    }

    template<typename U>
    some_class(const some_class<U> &other)
    : data(other.data)
    {}

private:
    T* data;

};

int main() {
    some_class<int> a;

    // Works OK!
    const some_class<int> const_b = a;

    // error: conversion from 'some_class<int>' to non-scalar type 'const some_class<const int>'
    const some_class<const int> const_c = a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This makes the code compile, but also allows you to convert a const_iterator into a non-const iterator.

Comment: Not according to this: https://ideone.com/aHwLAL `error: conversion from 'const some_class<const int>' to non-scalar type 'some_class<int>' requested`

Comment: But you can't cast const const_iterator to non-const iterator with STL iterators also. https://ideone.com/aEpNb8

Comment: I was thinking of converting a `some_class<const int>` to `some_class<int>` which would allow you to modify the `int`. https://ideone.com/4JaCiZ

Comment: I thought your question is how to cast non_const iterator to const, which is possible in STL. But it's not possible to cast STL iterators backwards.

Comment: Yes, your answer seems to do what I'm looking for. I'm still going over test cases.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add const to template constructor's declaration, see my edited version: some_class(some_class<U> const &other), it should compile now

Comment: Changing the constructor to const some_class<U>& other will allow it to compile but then iterator a = const_iterator b would also erroneously be true (as mentioned in the OP).

Comment: That is allowed because your constructor doesn't actually do anything, try my edited version of some_class

Answer (score -1):

Copy constructor should have a const reference and this code will compile

```
some_class(const some_class<U>& other){}
```

Comment: Changing the constructor to const some_class<U>& other will allow it to compile but then iterator a = const_iterator b would also erroneously be true (as mentioned in the OP).

Comment: Yes but it allows assigning a `const` object to a non-`const` object. This isn't allowed by STL iterators.