# Calls const instead of non-const access operator for iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, const-iterator

I want to build a custom iterator on top of one of STL iterators. Here is the stripped-down version of the code which I would expect to be compilable:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>

class Data
{
public:
  double x;
};

typedef std::list<Data> list_of_data;

template <class IteratorType>
class my_iterator :
     public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,
                          typename IteratorType::value_type >
{
public:
  //type of itself
  typedef my_iterator self;
  //type of underlying iterator
  typedef IteratorType list_iterator_type;

  my_iterator(list_iterator_type it) :
    m_it(it)
  {}//constructor.

  my_iterator(const self& source) :
    m_it(source.m_it)
  {}

  self& operator=(const self& source)
  {
    m_it = source.m_it;
    return *this;
  }//operator=

  bool operator==(self other)
  {
    return m_it == other.m_it;
  }

  bool operator!=(self other)
  {
    return m_it != other.m_it;
  }

  inline typename self::reference operator*()
  { return (*m_it);}

  inline const typename self::reference operator*() const
    { return (*m_it); }

  inline typename self::pointer operator->()
    { return &(*m_it); }

  inline const typename self::pointer operator->() const
    { return &(*m_it); }

  inline self& operator++()
  {
    ++m_it;
  }//operator++

  inline self operator++(int)
  {
    self tmp(*this);
    ++(*this);
    return tmp;
  }//operator++(int)

private:

  list_iterator_type m_it;
};

///non constant iterator over cells.
typedef my_iterator<list_of_data::iterator> iterator;
///constant iterator over cells.
typedef my_iterator<list_of_data::const_iterator> const_iterator;

int main()
{
  list_of_data test_list;
  Data a;
  test_list.push_back(a);
  test_list.push_back(a);
  test_list.push_back(a);
  for(const_iterator it  = const_iterator(test_list.begin()); 
                     it != const_iterator(test_list.end()); ++it)
  {
    double x = it->x;
    double y = (*it).x;
  }
}
```

However it shows the following error message :

```
test_list.cpp: In instantiation of ‘typename my_iterator<IteratorType>::self::pointer my_iterator<IteratorType>::operator->() [with IteratorType = std::_List_const_iterator<Data>; typename my_iterator<IteratorType>::self::pointer = Data*]’:
test_list.cpp:92:18:   required from here
test_list.cpp:55:21: error: invalid conversion from ‘const Data*’ to ‘std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, Data, long int, Data*, Data&>::pointer {aka Data*}’ [-fpermissive]
     { return &(*m_it); }
                     ^
test_list.cpp: In instantiation of ‘typename my_iterator<IteratorType>::self::reference my_iterator<IteratorType>::operator*() [with IteratorType = std::_List_const_iterator<Data>; typename my_iterator<IteratorType>::self::reference = Data&]’:
test_list.cpp:93:18:   required from here
test_list.cpp:49:18: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, Data, long int, Data*, Data&>::reference {aka Data&}’ from expression of type ‘const Data’
   { return (*m_it);}
```

as far as I can see it refers to non-const version of the access operator, but why, if I explicitly use constant iterator here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I finally found the problem, so I am posting the correct, compilable, version of the above code. Here are the highlights:

-- The main problem was that I under-defined template parameters for base std::iterator class. It takes 5 parameters, but I defined only first 2, relying on default type assignment for the rest. This was a mistake. For example by default `pointer` is defined as `value_type*`, but what I needed was actually `const value_type*` for constant iterator. I therefore defined all 5 template parameters.

-- There were no need to have 2 versions of `operator*()` and `operator->()`.

-- I also added another templated constructor to allow assigning non-const iterator to the const ones.

So below are results of my endeavours.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>

class Data
{
public:
  double x;
};

typedef std::list<Data> list_of_data;

template <class IteratorType>
class my_iterator :
     public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,
                          typename IteratorType::value_type,
                          typename IteratorType::difference_type,
                          typename IteratorType::pointer,
                          typename IteratorType::reference>
{
public:
  //type of itself
  typedef my_iterator self;
  //type of iterator over cells
  typedef IteratorType list_iterator_type;

  my_iterator(list_iterator_type it) :
    m_it(it)
  {}//constructor.

  my_iterator(const self& source) :
    m_it(source.m_it)
  {}

  template<class another_iterator>
  my_iterator(const my_iterator<another_iterator>& source) :
    m_it(source.m_it)
  {}

  self& operator=(const self& source)
  {
    m_it = source.m_it;
    return *this;
  }//operator=

  bool operator==(self other) const
  {
    return m_it == other.m_it;
  }

  bool operator!=(self other) const
  {
    return m_it != other.m_it;
  }

  inline typename self::reference operator*() const
  { return (*m_it);}

  inline typename self::pointer operator->() const
    { return &(*m_it); }

  inline self& operator++()
  {
    ++m_it;
    return (*this);
  }//operator++

  inline self operator++(int)
  {
    self tmp(*this);
    ++(*this);
    return tmp;
  }//operator++(int)

private:

  list_iterator_type m_it;
};

///non constant iterator over cells.
typedef my_iterator<list_of_data::iterator> iterator;
///constant iterator over cells.
typedef my_iterator<list_of_data::const_iterator> const_iterator;

int main()
{
  list_of_data test_list;
  Data a;
  test_list.push_back(a);
  test_list.push_back(a);
  test_list.push_back(a);
  for(iterator it  = iterator(test_list.begin()); 
                     it != iterator(test_list.end()); ++it)
  {
    it->x = 2;
  }
  for(const_iterator it  = const_iterator(test_list.begin()); 
                     it != const_iterator(test_list.end()); ++it)
  {
    std::cout << "  it->x =" << it->x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(*it).x =" << (*it).x << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `const_iterator it` in your for-loop, `it` is of type `const_iterator` but it is itself non-const.

Therefore using its member functions will use the non-const members, which doesn't work when the `my_iterator` stores a real `list::const_iterator`. In the expression `&(*m_it)`, the element referenced by `*m_it` is const, so you cannot get a non-const address to that object:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘const Data*’

Comment: Right. But how can I make it work then? For that matter, how does it work in STL?

Comment: You might want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35311638/597607) to another iterator question from earlier today.